# Looking for example code of a JavaFx TableView with only one Button inside a column?

Tags: java, button, javafx, tableview

What I am trying to create is a scrollable all button GUI layout. I was able to achieve this with 4 different ListViews but I didn't like the four scroll bars attached to the list views. The number of buttons will be figured out at run-time because it will depend on the number of entries in a database. I Think a TableView will be better for my situation.

[image]

Comment: A GridView would be a better solution

Comment: Thanks! Will try. Does the gidview add scrolling once the sum of the buttons height is greater than the view height?

Comment: No, you need to wrap it inside of an ScrollPane, then scrolling will be handled automatically

Comment: I just made an answer out of it, if it helps you please don't hesitate to accept it ;-)

Comment: I just checked the check under the up vote. Didn't know that's how it's done.  Once again thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a `GridPane` inside of an `ScrollPane` would be a better solution

```
<ScrollPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <content>
      <GridPane>
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

With this code you can add the amount of columns and rows which you need

```
myGridPane.getRowConstraints().clear();
myGridPane.getColumnConstraints().clear();

int numRow = 10;
int numCol = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
    RowConstraints rConstraint = new RowConstraints();
    rConstraint.setPercentHeight(100);
    myGridPane.getRowConstraints().add(rConstraint);
}

for (int i = 0; i < numCol; i++) {
    ColumnConstraints cConstraint = new ColumnConstraints();
    cConstraint.setPercentWidth(100);
    myGridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(cConstraint);
}
```

If you now want to put a button at a specific position inside of the `GridPane` you can do this with the static methods of the `GridPane` class

```
GridPane.setColumnIndex(myButtonXY, colX);
GridPane.setRowIndex(myButtonXY, colY);
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason GridPane.setColumnIndex(myButtonXY, colX); and GridPane.setRowIndex(myButtonXY, colY); would not work for me. I had to change it to myGridPane.add(myButtonXY, colx, coly);

Comment: Maybe this is because of the JDK version or JavaFX version :-)

Comment: If my answer helped you solving your problem please don't hesitate to accept it ;-)

Comment: I gave it an up vote.